# Ad banner with my ads

Tags: ios

I would like to make a banner that will display ads for my products only. Will it be ok with App Store or my app won't be approved (or cut later)?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can find in the App store review guidelines is this:
**2.25**

- Apps that display Apps other than your own for purchase or promotion 
  in a manner similar to or confusing with the App Store will be
  rejected, unless designed for a specific approved need (e.g. health
  management, aviation, accessibility, etc.) or which provide
  significant added value for a specific group of customers.

But you can't make it look like the standard i-ad banner because that means you are replicating an existing apple product.
**8.3**

- Apps that appear confusingly similar to an existing Apple product or 
  advertising theme will be rejected

And you must keep in mind that the ads can't be too annoying:
**2.13**

- Apps that are primarily marketing materials or advertisements will be
  rejected

If you follow these rules I would say go for it, it sounds to me like it is perfectly within apples rules what you are trying to do.

For the full apple app-store review guidelines go [here](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#advertising)